# Convert from VGA 9 pin to RCA (manually - old machine)

Tags: display, video, vga, rca

I'm in a trouble. Can someone help me?

I have a very big machine where I had mounted an IBM 5151 monitor by VGA. The VGA cable was connected to the card below (see attachment), by 4 wires.

Now the monitor is broken and I'm in  trouble. Can anyone help me?

I want to connect a single RCA wire (the yellow) directly in the card in place of the 4 wires of the VGA (wires grey, green, pink, white, to be clear.) The RCA cable has 2 wires, one yellow and one black.

What can I do?

Please it's really important.

[image]

Comment: Otherwise... I have a 9 pin vga output. I can use a transformer 9-pin to 15 and connect a normal LCD? The ibm 5151 has a low resolution and 50hrz of requence, any problem about??

Comment: No the output is not VGA. It is MDA. It is not compatible with VGA in any way. I am having trouble deciding if this is a repair question without understanding the device being repaired, what to buy question, or how to use devices question.

Comment: the circuit looks suspiciously like an MDA to compositie converter. find someone who knows the device they will tell you which pin has compositie video on it.

Comment: The configuration in photo works... i want to resolve it in any way possibile. I can't go to search for a IBM 5151... That's the big problem

Comment: @Jasen MDA being 18.4kHz 50Hz would not be compatible with composite 15.6kHz 50Hz.

Comment: Any MDA monitor will do. Or MDA to whatever you like converter box and modern monitor. It does not have to be IBM 5151.

Comment: I'm not sure what this "two mini cables" is; normally composite video is only one RCA plug (containing signal and ground). Is this maybe S-Video? But as Justme says, without a service manual for the device in question (or even any labels!) we're just guessing.

Comment: If the those colours are right they are running the display at half brightness. pin 4 is ground  abs pin pin 5, 3, or 2 is video.

Comment: The chip on the circuit board is a 74HCT14N. It's a Schmitt trigger (x6) which I assume is for the six inputs to the circuit board. It operates at TTL level (0 to 5 V), not VGA level (0 to 0.7 V)

Comment: old schools CRT monitors could have their sync rate adjusted easily,  LCD monitors may or may not be able to sync

Comment: The board (that includes 74HCT14N) is attached with the cable in the photo. This is the vga cable connected with the IBM monitor, modified from 9 pins to 6 pins (3 color pins removed).

Comment: Do you have a wiring diagram for the circuit board? Can you take the PCB out and trace the signals? If that cable really is a VGA cable (and not [MDA for IBM 5151](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_5151)), are the wires HSYNC, VSYNC, GREEN and GROUND?

Comment: Here's the [Original Monochrome Display and Parallel Printer Adapter found on the IBM PC (IBM 5150)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Monochrome_Display_Adapter#/media/File:IBM_PC_Original_Monochrome_Display_and_Parallel_Printer_Adapter.jpg). In the top-right corner you can see the 9-pin MDA output. It's not a 15-pin VGA output.

Comment: From my 5151 outputs a vga cable (without 3 pins). I'm looking for the machine circuit board

Comment: This is the output of actually (broken) 5151 => https://ibb.co/g4tMHYM
This be connected here => https://ibb.co/jkmymK0
By the cable in the photo ("This cable is 9 pin-vga")

Comment: That's the MDA connector and here are the [MDA pin-outs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Monochrome_Display_Adapter#Specifications).

Comment: Perfect dude. What can i do?

Comment: Make sure that it really is only the monitor that is broken. It could be the MDA card as well or instead of. Then [follow the advice of @pjc50](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/531946/248838).

Comment: Only the monitor is broken.
Circuit board => https://ibb.co/THhXwgC

Answer (score 12):

There are a number of problems you have here:

- VGA is 15 pins, not 9
- RCA is composite video, not VGA
- IBM 5151 is neither of those, it's an old standard "MDA" (monochrome display adapter).

It appears from the internet that MDA isn't a subset of VGA - you can't convert from one to the other by simple wiring.

Your options are:

- find an old IBM 5151 that is still working, or repair the broken one
- buy an [MDA to VGA converter](https://www.serdashop.com/MCE2VGA) and wire it appropriately. "Industrial" versions of these can be found on Aliexpress and other vendors; it seems that this is a common problem of industrial equipment with obsolete monitors.
- trace the video signals further back from that board and find a more useful one (unlikely, since this looks very old .. how old is it? 80s?)

Comment: I want to remove the VGA and put into the 1,3,4,6 slots (see the image) only 2 cables (the cables from the rca yellow). I had tried it and for seconds it works, but after removed it the connection was  losted... So i don't know where put the positive and the negative of rca (what slots from 1,3,4 or 6)...

Comment: @MarcAurel This answer clearly explains that there is no "VGA" here and that an MDA signal is not compatible with composite video, which makes your commenting pretending otherwise quite disappointing.  Until you recognize the reality of the situation there's really no way anyone can help you, that said the question isn't on topic here anyway.